# How do I fix background fetch crashing in iOS 15 and iOS 16?

Tags: ios, crash, background-fetch

## BackgroundFetch Crash in iOS15 and iOS16

```
Monitor Type:    Mach Exception
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001df8354b0
Crashed Thread:  0

Pthread id: 23896613
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   BaseBoard                       -[_BSActionResponder action_sendResponse:] + 528
1   BaseBoard                       -[_BSActionResponder action_sendResponse:] + 520
2   BaseBoard                       -[BSAction sendResponse:] + 76
3   UIKitServices                   -[UISFetchContentInBackgroundAction sendResponse:] + 100
4   UIKitCore                       __91-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_3 + 60
5   UIKitCore                       -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 72
6   UIKitCore                       -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 176
7   UIKitCore                       _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 496
8   UIKitCore                       _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 108
9   UIKitCore                       _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 72
10  UIKitCore                       _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84
11  UIKitCore                       schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 172
12  UIKitCore                       runloopSourceCallback + 92
13  CoreFoundation                  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
15  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
16  CoreFoundation                  __CFRunLoopRun + 836
17  CoreFoundation                  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
18  GraphicsServices                GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKitCore                       -[UIApplication _run] + 888
20  UIKitCore                       UIApplicationMain + 340
21  app                             main (main.m:43)
22  (null) 0x00000001f694e960 0x0 + 8431921504
```

**iOS15、iOS16 crashed in the background after enable the BackgroundFetch function, According to the log, all crash are in background and the crash is almost located. but how to fix it ??**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    if (self.currentCompletionHandler && self.currentCompletionHandler != completionHandler) {
        self.currentCompletionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
    self.currentCompletionHandler = completionHandler;
    
    //do something
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.currentCompletionHandler) {
**            self.currentCompletionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);  //crash line code
**            self.currentCompletionHandler = nil;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is with the `currentCompletionHandler` dance? You can't have multiple, concurrent background refresh tasks. Also, the `dispatch_after` is a bad smell.